# Xcode 4.6 Can't add outlet for text field as "connection" in popover is greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode

I need help adding an outlet for a text field in XCode 4.6.3.  (By way of background, I'm a newbie following Apple's "hello world" tute and am up to [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html).)

I control-drag the text field inside the method declaration then release.  In the pop-up that is displayed, "Connection" defaults to "Action" and is greyed out.  I can't change it to "Outlet".

How can I make it editable so I can choose "Outlet"?

Sorry about the lack of images but I'm too junior on Stack Overflow.  If you want a visual, feel free to go to the [Apple tute](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html), search for the text "*you can configure the action connection you just made*", then look at the image underneath.

Would appreciate any help as I'm pretty stuck.

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens if you control-drag into the *implementation* part of the view controller
in the .m file:

```
@implementation HelloWorldViewController
...
@end
```

Outlets connect a *property* of the view controller with an object in the xib file,
and properties are declared in the *interface* of an object.

Therefore, to create an outlet connection, control-drag into the public interface part
in the .h file:

```
@interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController
...
@end
```

This is what the tutorial shows.

**Alternatively**, you can make the property "private" to the implementation by 
control-dragging into the private extension interface in the .m file:

```
@interface HelloWorldViewController ()
...    
@end
```

This works with newer Xcode versions and helps to keep the public interface clean.

Comment: Thanks Martin! You're right, I had been working the implementation part of the view controller.  Hadn't realised.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag and drop textfield to view
2. click on editor as shown below blue circle [image]
3. right click on textfield and drag it to viewcontroller.h as shown below
   [image]
4. you will seet the box as shown below: enter your name for textfield
   [image]
5. click connect.

its done..

hope helps you