# Xcode 5: Trying to link text field to UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: No Dialog]

Hi, was shown that this was supposed to produce a dialog, such as in the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629040/xcode-4-6-cant-add-outlet-for-text-field-as-connection-in-popover-is-greyed-o)

Unfortunately, I am not. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure that this is the file owner of the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Select ViewController first.
>
> 2.Then go to Identity inspector(under view third tab) and select your_class where you are trying to link then class  will attach to the ViewController.
>
> 3.Then try to link.

Comment: Short and sweet. Thanks.

Comment: Always Welcome. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

First see the class of your fileOwner here:
[image]

Then change this icon to automatic and the selected class should have the same class as in the fileOwner 
[image]

Comment: do you understand where are all these should be ?

Comment: I can see the Detail View Controller, but it is Manual > DetailViewController.h > No Selection

Comment: @SherwynGoh yes should be automatic, let Xcode choose the file owner

Comment: thanks I'll keep it in mind, @python 's answer pointed me in the right direction though